# Background image of Anchor not working with Safari/Firefox

Tags: css, safari

I have following Css where i have used back-ground image. Then i am generating Anchor and assigning css class which has image. It works fine with IE but does not work with Safari,Firefox and Chrome.

Can anyone help me on how to fix it. I have given details below.

*CSS*

```
.HOME
{
   BACKGROUND-IMAGE: url(../images/home.jpg);
   WIDTH: 56px;
   BACKGROUND-REPEAT: no-repeat;
   HEIGHT: 20px
}
.HOME A
{
   WIDTH: 56px;
   HEIGHT: 20px
}
.HOME A:hover
{
   BACKGROUND-IMAGE: url(../images/home1.jpg);
   WIDTH: 56px;
   HEIGHT: 20px
}
```

*HTML*

```
<td class="HOME"><A href="#abc.html" Class ="Home" onclick="OpenPage()"/></td>
```

Comment: It would help to know the exact problem you experience with the other three browsers.

Answer (score 1):

background-image is getting be deprecated, I suggest to use:

```
a.home { background: url(../images/home.jpg) no-repeat; width:56px; height:20px }
a.home:hover { background: url(../images/home1.jpg); width:56px; height:20px }
```

Answer (score 0):

It would work if you would use the following CSS:

```
a.home { background-image:url(../images/home.jpg); width:56px; background-repeat:no-repeat; height:20px }
a.home:hover { background-image:url(../images/home1.jpg); width:56px; height:20px }
```

Comment: Yes, tested it in Opera, IE7, Chrome, FF and Safari. I see no reason why it shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do something similar and found out that adding position: relative or absolute makes it work on Chrome/Safari/Firefox.